# How to get data from $_REQUEST

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

When 'Papar' clicked, it should be go to view page. Primary key: 'IC NO'.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
$ic_no=$_REQUEST['ic_no'];
require_once "connection.php";
$conn=connect();
$db=connectdb();

mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die (mysql_error()."\n");
$query_usr="select * from aduan,pendaftaran";
$usr=mysql_query($query_usr,$conn) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$query_usr);
$row_usr=mysql_fetch_assoc($usr);
?>

<html><head></head><body>
<?php
$view="SELECT * FROM aduan,pendaftaran where $ic_no='ic_no'";
$result=mysql_query($view,$conn);
?>
<center><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<img src="imagess/header.jpg" width="1069" height="90" >
<table width="1059"><td height="59"></td>    

<td><fieldset>
<legend><b>Maklumat Aduan</b>
</legend>
<?php
$view = "SELECT * FROM aduan,pendaftaran";
$result = mysql_query ($view, $conn);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<center><table width="585" height="100" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="424">NAMA PELAJAR</td>
    <td width="24">:</td>
     <td width="300"><?php echo $row["nama"];?></td>

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>IC</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row["ic_no"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMAIL</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TEL NO</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["tel_no"];?></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>JANTINA</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["jantina"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MATRIK NO</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["matrik_no"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>JABATAN</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["jabatan"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ALAMAT</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["alamat"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>POSKOD</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["poskod"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NEGERI</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["state"];?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="424">ID GERAI</td>
    <td width="24">:</td>
     <td width="300"><?php echo $row["id_gerai"];?></td>

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>JENIS ADUAN </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row["jenis_aduan"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TARIKH</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row["tarikh"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <tr>
    <td>LOKASI</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["lokasi"];?></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>MAKLUMAT ADUAN</td>
    <td>:</td>
     <td><?php echo $row["aduan"];?></td>
  </tr>

  </div>
</table>
</form></br>
</fieldset></td></center>

</div> 

</body></html>
```

When I click to 'Papar' (second row) which is data for second user,
Its still show data from the first user.

[image]

Please help me out
Anyone?

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `$_REQUEST` data should **NEVER** go directly into a query. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I immediately see is

```
$view="SELECT * FROM aduan,pendaftaran where $ic_no='ic_no'";
```

your column and parameters are backwards.  It should be

```
'ic_no' = $ic_no
```

at the very least.